# How do I fix an internal error on IBM CPLEX?

Tags: cplex

I have a code that was running without issue until I tried to pull additional data from a local excel file. It was working fine until the line below was added:
p from SheetRead(Sheet,"'Selection'!F1:F17");;

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to resolve it! Thank you :)

Comment: Can you please tell exacty what the error is? Please show the exact error message and, if available, the backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

1) Do you run on windows ?
2) Do you have Excel installed ?
3) Can you check whether the oil example with excel works in order to know whether the connection with excel works ?